# Converting NOAA Nautical s57 ENC to shapefiles for use in QGIS on Mac - missing .prj files?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, mac, noaa

I have been attempting to follow the instructions given on the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9W5TmXSMsRk

which is basically an English version of this:

https://www.sigterritoires.fr/index.php/en/displaying-marine-charts-with-s57-qgis/

This demonstration uses FWTools on Windows to convert the s57 file into individual shapefiles.

I am on OSX and tried to use GDAL with the ogr2ogr – skipfailures command, and while it generates output, I suspect it is not complete.
Yes, there were tons of errors and warning upon running the script, but the video says those can be ignored. However I did notice that unlike the file list seen on the video, my 'translated' file directory did not contain any .prj files.
Should there be .prj files? And if so, and thoughts as to why my conversion did not generate them?

Here are some of the tyes of errors I received when running ogr2ogr:

```
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support StringList type for field TECSOU. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type StringList on shapefile layers.
ERROR 1: Attempt to write non-polygon (POINT) geometry to POLYGON type shapefile.
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support IntegerList type for field FFPT_RIND. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type IntegerList on shapefile layers.
```

among others.